# Can't integrate with dblquad

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.6, quad

So I want to integrate a double integral with constants in it, like a, b, etc where the user can asign the value of this constants:

The limits of the integral are x[0,1] and y[-1,2]

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def g(y,x,a):
    return a*x*y

a = int(input('Insert a value --> '))
result = integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 1, lambda x: -1, lambda x: 2, args=(a))[0]
print(result)
```

But I get this error and I don't understant why:

```
TypeError: integrate() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

I don't understand it. Because when I do the same but with quad() Python does it correctly:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def g(x,a):
    return a*x

a = int(input('Insert a value --> '))
result = integrate.quad(g, 0, 1, args=(a))[0]
print(result)
```

With the result:

```
0.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the value you provide in the optional argument args is a tuple. In the case of [quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), it is what the function expects, but for [dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html), a sequence is required. Even though tuples are [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) (immutable ones), it seems that scipy makes a difference here and therefore it is why an error is raised. However it is misleading as a tuple is definitely an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). Anyway, this should work:

```
result = integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 1, lambda x: -1, lambda x: 2, args=[a])[0]
```

Comment: *"The problem here is that the value you provide in the optional argument args is a tuple. "*  Actually, `(a)` is not a tuple; it is exactly the same as `a`.  To make a tuple of length 1 containing `a`, use `(a,)`.  (Your solution works too.)